# Как и где разместить json файлы?

Tags: java, android, json, сервер, api

Допустим у меня есть много json файлов. Где я могу их разместить, чтобы потом получить их на устройство, в процессе, их нужно будет изменять. Нужен какой-то хостинг или есть сервисы для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно JSON генерируется программно под конкретный запрос клиента. Если вы все же хотите использовать готовые файлы, то закачиваете их на любой хостинг, а далее обращаетесь к ним напрямую или через скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, если вы хотите чтобы изменения в `JSON` видели и другие ваши устройства, то лучше хранить на хостинге, можно и на бесплатном.

Но а если, изменения в `JSON` должен видеть именно то устройство на котором ваше приложение, и другим устройствам ваш этот Измененный `Json` не нужен, так как у них будут свои `JSON`, то можете хранить в папке `assets`